# Hibernate oneToOne join with additional criteria

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I need to do a join in hibernate, but I want to exclude some results from being found. I've tried using `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas`, but I still get all results

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value= "(select a.seller_sku from de_products a where a.asin = 'a' and a.product_name != '' and a.seller_sku != '' and a.seller_sku = sku)", referencedColumnName = "seller_sku")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "sku", referencedColumnName = "seller_sku", insertable = false, updatable = false))
})
public DeProducts getDeProduct() {
    return deProduct;
}
```

If I try it without the `column` definition

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value= "(select a.seller_sku from de_products a where a.asin = 'a' and a.product_name != '' and a.seller_sku != '' and a.seller_sku = sku)", referencedColumnName = "seller_sku"))
})
public DeProducts getDeProduct() {
    return deProduct;
}
```

I get an NullPointerException on application startup, at

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory

How do I do a join with spring-boot (1.4) hibernate (5.2.2.Final) with additional criterias/exclusions?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution that works. Hibernate seems to ignore the @JoinForumula when referencing the same column in the formula and in the @JoinColumn annotation. When referencing another column in the formula - e.g. `id`, it works.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(select a.id from de_products a where a.asin != '' and a.product_name = 'a' and a.seller_sku = sku)", 
              referencedColumnName = "id")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "sku", referencedColumnName = "seller_sku", insertable = false, updatable = false))
})
public DeProducts getDeProduct() {
    return deProduct;
}
```