# Hibernate @OneToOne self join with OR in join clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `@OneToOne` annotation which I want to join on 2 possible columns. I know how to do it with a plain SQL query, but I have no idea how this could work with hibernate annotations.

Following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cancelRecord")
    private Foo cancelRecord;

    private String externalId;
    private String externalCancellationId;
}
```

and the corresponding database table:

```
create table Foo(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key, --primary key
    cancelRecord int,
    externalId varchar(100),
    externalCancellationId varchar(100)
)
```

So far `cancelRecord` is only joined on that column. Now I want it to join on either `cancelRecord` or `externalCancellationId`. A valid SQL query for that would be:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM Foo f 
        INNER JOIN Foo fo 
        ON (f.cancelRecord = fo.id 
        OR f.externalCancellationId = fo.externalId)
```

The crucial part about this query is the **`OR`** in the join clause `(f.cancelRecord = fo.id **OR** f.externalCancellationId = fo.externalId)`.

I assume that this is not possible with `@JoinColumn` and I'd need to rely on `@JoinFormula` in some way.

**Is that assumption right? If so, would I simply need to copy the above query as `@JoinFormula`?**

---

I tried to use this `@JoinFoluma`:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinFormula(value = "SELECT f.* 
        FROM Foo f 
        INNER JOIN Foo fo 
        ON (f.cancelRecord = fo.id 
        OR f.externalCancellationId = fo.externalId)")
private Foo cancelRecord;
```

This causes an `NullPointerException` when loading the spring context:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/test-database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindOneToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:3185)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1798)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:961)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

EDIT:

Exception resolved with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892267/hibernate-onetoone-join-with-additional-criteria), but sadly this again ends with an `AND` instead of an `OR`.

Comment: `@JoinFormula` would seem to be what you want.

Comment: Thats what I already thought. Do I need to include the whole query as plain SQL query?

Comment: Would appear so.

Comment: Just select the ID i.e. `f.id` rather than `f.*`

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help with the exception. I tried to add `referencedColumnName` to the `@JoinFormula`, but that doesn't work either

Comment: The whole query has to be wrapped in brackets I think. Not sure the lack of them would be causing the exception seen however.

Comment: Can't get it to work in any way because of that exception. Will ask a follow up question about that exception

Comment: Could resolve the issue, but by resolving the issue, I went back to an `AND` instead of the needed `OR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work since the `@JoinColumn` or `@JoinFormula` are used to determine Foreign Key column value, so they don't work with multiple columns.

If you define multiple `@JoinColumn` or `@JoinFormula`, then the ON relationship will use an `AND` not an `OR`.

In your case, since you probably only want to read this association, as opposed to setting it using Hibernate, then you are better off using an SQL query instead.

Comment: Which approach would you suggest to set keep `@JoinColumn` functionality, but also set the `Foo cancelRecord;` with an SQL query? Would I need to use a `ResultTransformer` to set the `cancelRecord` manually?

Comment: `ResultTransformer` is for transforming the `Object[]` result into a DTO or Pojo. In your case, you cannot use Hibernate to set the association unless you write a custom Type for that. Otherwise, how would HIbernate know which of those two columns to set and based on what logic?

Comment: Good question. I now am using a HQL to get the base object with `@JoinColumn` and then check if `cancelRecord` is null and if `externalCancellationId` is set. If that is the case, I run a second HQL to get the cancellation record and set that one to the original entry.

Answer (score -2):

You can use more than one `@JoinColumn` annotation. See an example below:

```
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumns(
     {
       @JoinColumn(updatable=false,insertable=false, name="cancelRecord", referencedColumnName="cancelRecord"),
       @JoinColumn(updatable=false,insertable=false, name="other", referencedColumnName="other")
     }
   )
   private Foo cancelRecord;
```

Comment: Does that act as an `OR`? I always thought it would act as an `AND`

Comment: Don't think that is useful here. The questioner wants to join on A **or** B, not A **and** B.